# Matching against type hierarchy

Tags: java, design-patterns, types, casting, hierarchy

Suppose we have a fixed type hierarchy, e.g. as depicted below. It is a well-defined tree, where each node has one parent (except for the root).

[image: Human taxonomy]

Each type has an action associated with it, that should be performed upon successful matching. This does **not** mean that an action corresponds to a method on said type. It's just arbitrary association.

What are intelligent ways to match objects against a type hierarchy? 
Each object should be matched against the most specific type possible. The objects are already created.

Comment: The solution I have in mind is traversing a tree of tuples of type and associated action.

Comment: Do you want to check the type of a given object? Can you give us a code example?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you have objects belonging to the above class/type hierarchy, and methods representing actions, then calling those methods on the objects will automatically invoke the most specific action.

Comment: I can't change the objects, thus can't utilize polymorphism. I want to classify foreign objects with foreign interfaces.

Comment: @mike does your use case involve responding to single objects or does the whole tree need to be traversed and actions performed on every memeber of the tree?

Comment: Do you have control over the instantiation of the objects? If so, you could use adapters.

Comment: I don't have control over the instantiation.

Comment: do all your actions have the same signature?

Comment: I don't think that's a problem here. Even if not, one extra layer of abstraction would solve it.

Comment: It would seem that if `action()` is the designated method defined by the superclass, then on calling that method on each object reference, the intended implementation of `action()` would get called. No?

Comment: *Each type has an action associated with it*. Can this action be defined by a contract. For example, do all the classes in the *hierarchy* have a method with the same signature? Do you have a tree data structure of these objects?

Comment: There is no method. Do not focus on the action. It's just an arbitrary association on my side that means nothing to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive search from the root.

Once no match can be found in children, remember the matched object if its level is deeper than the last match.

Pseudocode:

```
    class MatchContext {
         public int level;
         public Node result;
    }

    public boolean match(Node object, int level, MatchContext ctx) {
        if (no match)
            return false;
        boolean found = false;
        for (all children in object) {
            if (match(child, level + 1, ctx))
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found && level > ctx.level) {
            ctx.level = level;
            ctx.result = this;
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Invoke it like this:

```
    MatchContext ctx;
    if (match(root, 0, ctx))
        myAction(ctx.result);
```

Comment: My intuition was also a tree. This yields O(log n) matches max.

Comment: There's an error in the last if condition. In order to get matches on root level, you to combine `ctx.level == 0 && level == 0` and `level < ctx.level` with an logical or.

Answer (score 0):

The tree hierarchy is already implicitly defined by the declaration of the classes. You just need to traverse one tree branch via chained `getSuperclass()` calls to the type you want to lookup. The tree nodes(class types) can then be organized using a simple hash map.

**Given that the type hierarchy is static, you could define it as enum**

```
public enum ClassType{
    HOMINOIDEA(HOMINOIDEA.class),
    HOMINIDAE(HOMINIDAE.class),
    HOMININAE(HOMININAE.class),
    //and so on
    UNKNOWN(null);      

    private static final Map<Class<?>, ClassType> typesMap = new HashMap<>();
    public final Class<?> type;

    static{
        for (ClassType classType : EnumSet.allOf(ClassType.class)){             
            if(classType.type != null){
                typesMap.put(classType.type, classType);
            }
        }
    }

    private ClassType(Class<?> type){
        this.type = type;           
    }

    public static ClassType getClassTypeOf(Class<?> type){
        for(Class<?> lookupType = type; lookupType != null; lookupType = lookupType.getSuperclass()){
            ClassType classType = typesMap.get(lookupType);
            if(classType != null){
                return classType;
            }
        }       
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

and then map the class types to actions:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    EnumMap<ClassType, Action> actionMap = new EnumMap<>(ClassType.class);
    actionMap.put(ClassType.HOMININAE, new HomininaeAction());
    Homininae h = new Homininae();
    actionMap.get(ClassType.getClassTypeOf(h)); //action associated with homininaes     
}
```

---

**Here is an other in some terms more dynamic version**

```
public class ActionDispatcher {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> actionMap = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void registerAction(Class<T> type, Consumer<? super T> action){
        actionMap.put(type, action);
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void dispatchActionFor(Object object){
        Consumer<Object> action = ((Consumer<Object>)getActionFor(object.getClass()));
        if(action != null){
            action.accept(object);
        }
    }

    private Consumer<?> getActionFor(Class<?> type){        
        for(Class<?> lookupType = type; lookupType != null; lookupType = lookupType.getSuperclass()){
            Consumer<?> action = actionMap.get(lookupType);
            if(action != null){
                return action;
            }
        }       
        return null;
    }

    //demo
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ActionDispatcher dispatcher = new ActionDispatcher();
        dispatcher.registerAction(Number.class, n -> System.out.println("number: " + n));
        dispatcher.registerAction(Double.class, d -> System.out.println("double: " + d));
        dispatcher.registerAction(String.class, s -> System.out.println("first char: " + s.charAt(0)));
        dispatcher.registerAction(Object.class, o -> System.out.println("object: " + o));

        dispatcher.dispatchActionFor(new Integer(3)); 
        dispatcher.dispatchActionFor(new Double(3.0));
        dispatcher.dispatchActionFor("string");
        dispatcher.dispatchActionFor(new Thread());
    }

}
```

The output of this is:

```
number: 3
double: 3.0
first char: s
object: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
```

Comment: Also thought about hashing, but is has a flaw which you tried to solve in your second approach. Hashing loses the hierarchical relationship between the types. Your second approach also has a minor flow, since it does not distinguish between types (or interfaces) and the actual classes. A class could implemented different interfaces, this would destroy the tree, since a node's parent wouldn't be well-defined anymore.

Comment: @mike Also in the first approach happens superclass-lookup - in `getClassTypeOf()`. I thought there is a well-defined type hierarchy given and you want to match against this given hierarchy. How can a given well-defined tree be "destroyed"? However both approaches should be adaptable to the presence of interfaces using  `getInterfaces()` in the lookup functions.

Comment: Ah, sorry my mistake. Related to the types: there is a difference between types and classes. Or in Java terms interfaces and classes. Yes, your solution would work, **but** the solution of @RustyX is more stable, since it's invariant to the actual implementing classes.