# Decouple case selection from processing

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns, optimization, switch-statement

I am processing data and there are a number of cases to process. Selecting the correct case involves some complexity, and so does processing once the correct case is found.

I can approach the problem in two different ways:

- (A) a method selects the correct process and calls it
- (B) a method carries out the selection, returns a code to another that controls the process.

(A) was my first option, but (B) has the advantage of decoupling the selection process, making it clearer, and separating it from the processing as such.

In pseudo code:

```
====== option A ======

function doEverything(data) {
   if (case1(data))
       return doCase1(data)
   else {
       doStuff(data) // applies to all cases except case1
       if (case2(data)) {
          doStuff2()
          return doCase2(data)
       }
       else if (case3(data)) {
          return doCase3(data)
       }
       else return doDefaultCase(data)
   }
   return result
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
====== option B ======

function doChoice(data) {
   if (case1(data)) return 1
   doStuff(data) // applies to all except case1
   if (case2(data)) return 2
   if (case3(data)) return 3
   return 4 // default
}

function doProcess(data) {
   which = choice(data)
   switch (which) {
   case 1:
      return doCase1(data)
      break
   case 2:
      doStuff2()
      return doCase2(data)
      break
   case 3:
      return doCase3(data)
      break
   case 4:
      return doDefaultCase(data)
   default:
      raise an error
}
```

My questions is: is there standard practice that applies to this sort of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002904/matching-against-type-hierarchy): I wanted to **dynamically** match against a **type hierachy** and then perform a specific action upon matching.

Instead of having a method consisting of if/else constructs, which encapsulate the rules for matching. You can even go a step further and decouple the matching method from its behavior, i.e. generalize it to match on rules, which it retrieves as method parameters.

This is possible, if you encapsulate the rules/conditions for matching in a hierachy as depicted below. Later you can use this hierachy for matching and use an action according to the matched type.

[image: example hierarchy]

---

In order to match against a type hierachy, which is essentially a tree of nodes, take a look at following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003016/1809463).